# authentication using openldap with apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, openldap

Im trying to make restrict access to a folder using a an authenticated ldap user, this used to work with apache on ubunbt 14.04, however now im trying to me to 16.04, however it does not work, i get AH1618 user not found errors, im sure its something simple :)

the users are in this "domain" `ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=kattronics,dc=com`

When accessing the webpage, i get prompted for the password which is good, however i get this error.

> [auth_basic:error] [pid 10821] [client 10.0.5.167:58662] AH01618: user lasse.knudsen not found: /

Maybe there is a clue in the trailing slash

Debugging is enabled for apache2

> AH01694: auth_ldap authenticate: user lasse.knudsen authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Can't contact LDAP server] (not authoritative)

The cant contact LDAP server, puzzles me, the host does resolve.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction.

Directory entry from apache site configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AuthName "Restricted - Kattronics Users Only"
  AuthType Basic
  #Satisfy any
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPUrl "ldaps://dc2-ldap001:636/ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=kattronics,dc=com?uid"
  AuthLDAPBindDN "ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=kattronics,dc=com"
  AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
  AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
  #Require valid-user
  Require ldap-user # Gives error AH01618
</Directory>
```

Workaround below

```
 <IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
  AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
  SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
 </IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/html>
                         AuthType Basic
                         AuthName "Login"
                         AuthBasicProvider external
                         AuthExternal pwauth
                         Require valid-user

                </Directory>
```

Comment: The BindDN isn't valid as well, this should be a user; The BindDN is usually accompanied by a password. The OU should be a SearchBase.

Comment: Im really confused regarding what settings are needed and which are not.

Comment: Please make sure that your config files appear heer exactly like in your machine. As an example, do you really have a line break in the `AuthLDAPUrl` parameter?

Comment: sven, i have removed the line wrapping, now the contents are like they where at the time of posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most LDAP servers require you to authenticate before you can request any useful directory information. In LDAP jargon connection is called to "*bind*" to the directory server.

That means that Apache will need to be configured with a username and password. The username needs to be the full Distinct Name that includes the full path in the directory where it is stored and your [`AuthLDAPBindDN`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbinddn) needs to look something like:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=apache,OU=Service Accounts,DC=example,DC=com"
```

and you probaly need a [`AuthLDAPBindPassword`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbindpassword) (preferably one that never expires) as well:

```
AuthLDAPBindPassword  y0ur_p@ssw0rd
```

A second issue when using a TLS/SSL secured LDAP connection is that Apache will need to verify the authenticity of the server certificate the LDAP server uses. Typically I would expect that an LDAP server does not use a certificate issued by one of the well known public CA's but rather one issued by an internal CA. Download the CA certificate to your web server and load it with [`LDAPTrustedGlobalCert`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html#ldaptrustedglobalcert) directive i.e.

```
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert type directory-path/filename [password]
```

Alternatively as an insecure work-around, use the  [`LDAPVerifyServerCert`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html#ldapverifyservercert) directive and don't verify the server certificate:

```
LDAPVerifyServerCert          off
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I fixed it with a workaround, by using system user authentication, this solved the issue for me, as a workaround